# Comparing magnesium ion sensitivity in ribosomes to sensitivity in double-stranded DNA

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, structural-biology

I was doing some reading on this, and $\ce{Mg^2+}$ has a much greater sensitivity to ribosomes than to dsDNA (double-stranded DNA). It seems the best answer I can think of it that $\ce{Mg^2+}$ provides greater stability and complexation to ribosomes, while it is not as crucial to dsDNA.

Does anyone have a better biochemical explanation why?

Comment: cross-posted http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57428/magnesium-has-a-greater-sensitivity-to-ribosomes-than-to-dsdna-why